# unable to get span value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm new to Javascript and Jquery, just started learning, I copied code from other website and do some slight changes, I'm trying to update the timer when clicking on icons, but I received this error:-
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

After finding, I see that variable myTime is undefined. It did not get span value. Here is my code:-

```
    function updateTimer(expiryid) {
            var myTime = $(expiryid+ ' span').html();
            console.log(myTime);
            var ss = myTime.split(":");
            var dt = new Date();
            dt.setHours(0);
            dt.setMinutes(ss[0]);
            dt.setSeconds(ss[1]);

            var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() + 1000);
            var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
            var ts = temp[0].split(":");

            expiryid.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
        }


     function initialize() {
     // Some un-related code up here

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        //console.log('expire_'+i);
                        updateTimer('#expire_'+i);
                    }
                })(marker, i));

    }

</script>

    <span id="expire_4">06:51</span>
```

Comment: what is span ? is that var ? can you add html or fiddle ?

Comment: @maky span is a html, I can't add to fiddle, it won't work because I'm mixing PHP in as well.

Comment: Why not `$(expiryid).html().split(':')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You html is `<span id="expire_4">06:51</span>` yet you are trying to query `var myTime = $(expiryid+ ' span').html();` where `expiryid = '#expire_'+i`. The issue is your query doesn't match your code.  Your query suggests that you expect there to be an element with id `expire_<number>` that has a child span. What you have is a span with id `expire_<number>`. Update the query to get the span element as `$(expiryid)` and you should be good to go.

**Edit** I also noticed you are trying to update the html of a variable. Update the entire function to:

```
function updateTimer(expiryid) {
            var myTimeEl = $(expiryid); /* create jquery object*/
            var myTime = myTimeEl.html(); /*get the date string*/
            console.log(myTime);
            var ss = myTime.split(":");
            var dt = new Date();
            dt.setHours(0);
            dt.setMinutes(ss[0]);
            dt.setSeconds(ss[1]);

            var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() + 1000);
            var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
            var ts = temp[0].split(":");

            myTimeEl.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]); /*add new string to element using jquery objct*/
        }
```

Comment: I tried, but I received this error.

`(index):52 Uncaught TypeError: expiryid.html is not a function`

Comment: @NickyMan Yea see my section under **Edit** `myTimeEl.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);` is the update. You can't use `.html` on a string!!! you need a jquery object like what i updated the function to

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks! I have been trying to figure out what are you saying.